# Get portlet type in Liferay 6.2 Hook

Tags: liferay-6.2, liferay-hook

Inside Liferay 6.2 **hook** I want to **know the portlet type**(Asset Publisher/Web Content Display). Portlet name wont help me because User may have used custom title and in that case "Asset Publisher"/"Web Content Display" wont be accessible to me.

Exact hook file location where i want Portlet-type is: **/html/portlet/portlet_css/view.jsp**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well without hooking other parts of Liferay you can't get it there (in java code). Portlet "Portlet CSS" is populated via javascript so there was apparently no need to send portletid as parameter.

To get portletId you should also hook /html/js/liferay/look_and_feel.js

```
autoLoad: false,
showLoading: false,
data: {
    p_l_id: themeDisplay.getPlid(),
    p_p_id: 113,
    p_p_state: EXCLUSIVE,
    doAsUserId: themeDisplay.getDoAsUserIdEncoded()
},
uri: themeDisplay.getPathMain() + '/portal/render_portlet'
```

modify it to be something like this

```
autoLoad: false,
showLoading: false,
data: {
    p_l_id: themeDisplay.getPlid(),
    p_p_id: 113,
    p_p_state: EXCLUSIVE,
    doAsUserId: themeDisplay.getDoAsUserIdEncoded(),
    _113_portletId: instance._portletId
},
uri: themeDisplay.getPathMain() + '/portal/render_portlet'
```

**comma** and **_113_portletId: instance._portletId** were added.

After that you can put in hooked /html/portlet/portlet_css/view.jsp

```
String portletId = (String) renderRequest.getParameter("portletId");
```

portletId for Asset publisher will be something like **101_INSTANCE_reKokSN3aDaL**

portletId for Web Content Display will be something like 
**56_INSTANCE_dxNxXuQ7ZuvB**

so you can test wether portletId starts with 101, 56, ...

You can also get Portlet object with

```
PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortletById(portletId);
```

UPDATE (answer to question in comment):

This portlet was not intended for such use, once it loads it stays rendered in html and all modifications are made with javascript.

When "Look and feel" is opened for first time after page load XHR request to server is made and "/html/portlet/portlet_css/view.jsp" is rendered. 
Second time (for another portlet on the same page), javascript prepares modal for another (or same) porlet, "/html/portlet/portlet_css/view.jsp" will not be rendered again.

To force rerendering of "/html/portlet/portlet_css/view.jsp" modify again "/html/js/liferay/look_and_feel.js".

after (in my source it is line 136)

```
if (!content) {
    content = A.Node.create('<div class="loading-animation" />');
}
```

add this

```
if (instance._currentPopup) {
    A.one("#" + instance._currentPopup.get("id")).remove()
    instance._currentPopup = null;
}
```

It should be before

```
if (!instance._currentPopup) {
    instance._currentPopup = Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow(
    ...
```

Clear Liferay and browser cache.

Comment: thanks. but why i am getting the same portlet ids for all portlet. when i am refreshing the page then only i am getting the new id

Answer (score 0):

You could get PortletDisplay object from ThemeDisplay context object and from PortletDisplay, you can get Title, PortletName etc.

Note that themeDisplay is already available and used in your jsp  /html/portlet/portlet_css/view.jsp

`PortletDisplay portletDisplay = themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay();
String title=portletDisplay.getTitle();
String portletName=portletDisplay.getPortletName();`